# How to connect to a Bitcoin testnet running in a docker container

Tags: node.js, docker, bitcoin, bitcoind, bitcoin-testnet

I am testing some Bitcoin related code and in order to test it have installed [bitcoin-testnet-box](https://github.com/freewil/bitcoin-testnet-box) within a [docker](http://www.docker.io) container.

It's running fine, and, within the container I can execute commands and see the results.

The Dockerfile is [exposing port 19001](https://github.com/freewil/bitcoin-testnet-box/blob/master/Dockerfile#L51), which I am mapping to port `49155` as the RPC port for one of the `bitcond` instances and I am trying to communicate with it using [node-bitcoin](https://github.com/freewil/node-bitcoin).

I've written a simple test which aims simply to get the current difficulty.

```
var bitcoin = require('bitcoin'),
    client = new bitcoin.Client({
      host: "192.168.59.103",
      port: 49155,
      user: "admin1",
      pass: "123"
    });

describe("Core Wallet Functions", function() {

  it("can get the current bitcoin difficulty", function(done){
    client.getDifficulty(function(err, difficulty){
      console.log("got response", err, difficulty);
      expect(err).to.equal(null);
      expect(difficulty).to.equal(1);
      done();
    });
  });
});
```

This was failing (*see update below*) with the error:

{ [Error: connect ECONNREFUSED]
    code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
    errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
    syscall: 'connect' }

A quick look at `docker ps` shows

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                                COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                                NAMES
8b04ed26d9e3        freewil/bitcoin-testnet-box:latest   /bin/bash           3 hours ago         Up 8 minutes        0.0.0.0:49155->19001/tcp, 0.0.0.0:49156->19011/tcp   bitcoind
```

I tried changing the host to both "localhost" and to "0.0.0.0" but got the same result.

Clearly I am missing something simple as the [node-bitcoin tests](https://github.com/freewil/node-bitcoin/blob/master/test/index.js) are not really doing anything different.

The command used to run the `bitcoin-testnet-box` was

```
docker run -ti --name bitcoind -P -p 49155:19001 freewil/bitcoin-testnet-box
```

What might I be doing wrong?

**Update**

I changed `bitcoin.conf` as suggested below and now the error message is

```
[Error: Invalid params, response status code: 403]
```

My `bitcoin.conf` looks like

```
# testnet-box functionality
testnet=1
dnsseed=0
upnp=0

rpcallowip=192.168.59.103
rpcallowip=192.168.1.4
rpcallowip=0.0.0.0

# listen on different ports than default testnet
port=19000
rpcport=19001

# always run a server, even with bitcoin-qt
server=1

# enable SSL for RPC server
#rpcssl=1

rpcuser=admin1
rpcpassword=123
```

**another update**

It's worth explaining that I am running `docker` on my Mac using `boot2docker` so the IP number I am referring to is the IP that is displayed when I run `docker ip`, not the IP of my Mac itself. I'm running the test using `NodeJS` on my Mac, not in the boot2docker VM or the actual Docker container. So, I've tried adding `rpcallowip=192.168.1.4` (where `192.168.1.4` is my Mac's IP) to my `bitcoind.conf` files too just in case. Alas that made no difference, I am still getting the `{ [Error: Invalid params, response status code: 403] code: -32602 }` response.

I have also triple-checked my username and password against what's in the bitcoin.conf file.

Per Chris McKinnel's suggestion below I have run `netstat -tunlp` within the docker container and it shows:

```
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:19000           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      65/bitcoind     
tcp6       0      0 :::19000                :::*                    LISTEN      65/bitcoind     
tcp6       0      0 :::19001                :::*                    LISTEN      65/bitcoind     
tcp6       0      0 :::19011                :::*                    LISTEN      75/bitcoind
```

So I also added `rpcallowip=0.0.0.0` to my `bitcoin.conf` file. Alas still no difference.

**finally a solution**

Thanks again to Chris McKinnel below setting `rpcallowip=*` solved the problem.  Of course this raises a whole new problem but I'll burn that bridge when I get to it.  For now I can test my Bitcoin processes quite happily.

Comment: Are you trying to connect to the docker client from inside the VM or from outside the VM?

Comment: I'm trying to connect from outside the VM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you'll need to add `rpcallowip=192.168.59.103` to both of your `bitcoin.conf` files for the nodes. By default `bitcoind` will only listen for RPC connections on localhost (according to [the docs](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Running_Bitcoin#Bitcoin.conf_Configuration_File)).

Once you've added your IP to the allow list, you can check to see if it has worked by doing a `telnet 192.168.59.103 19001`.

To see a list of what your PCs open ports (and from where they're accepting connections), do a `netstat -tunlp`.

Comment: Thanks Chris that helped. `telnet 192.168.59.103 49155` was able to connect but got bounced.  Running my test again returned `[Error: Invalid params, response status code: 403]` which is better but still not quite there.

Comment: 403 means forbidden. Are you sure your passing in the password/username like it wants it?

Comment: Thanks @tkone I've triple checked the `user: "admin1"` and `pass: "123"` values and compared them to the `rpcuser=admin1` and `rpcpassword=123` lines in the `bitcoin.conf` file and they match perfectly. I've also cross referenced with the [test over at the `node-bitcoin` project](https://github.com/freewil/node-bitcoin/blob/master/test/index.js#L90) and I can't see a difference.

Comment: Ah, you're using `boot2docker` - have you forwarded the range of docker ports from your `boot2docker` VM to your host? What does `netstat -tunlp` look like from within your container? Try setting `rpcallowip=*` in your config to see if that makes a difference.

Comment: w00t! thanks @ChrisMcKinnel setting `rpcallowip=*` worked. So now I need to work out how to narrow that down. That's a whole different question however.

Comment: You'll be able to see where the connection is coming from by doing an `strace -f -p PID` in your container where PID is the process ID of `bitcoind`

Answer (score 1):

I would just change

`rpcallowip=192.168.*.*`

That way it as at least in a C class range

Comment: Good idea Sam - I'm looking for a way to tell **exactly** what IP `bitcoind` is seeing so I can tighten this up; but for my testing purposes this is okay for now.